# Place the value of the input text field in the href attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to place the value of the text field inside the anchor tag `href` attribute this will be in loop i.e multiple rows will be there

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity" id='quantity' 
    value="<?php echo $data["quantity"]; ?>" size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="checkout.php?action=add&code=<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $data["code"]); ?>&quantity=6">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </a>
```

Comment: remember to make `urlencode($data["code"])` if there can be spaces or other forbidden characters

Comment: when do you want to do that? onload? when you type in?

Comment: when i type in the text field it should apply

Comment: Right, give me an example as to how the new href would look if I typed "mytext" in the input box.

Comment: <a href="checkout.php?action=add&code=<?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $data["code"]); ?>&quantity=mytext">

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').attr('href',$('#quantity').val());
```

I recommend you add an `id` or `class` attribute to your `a` element so you can identify it better.

**UPDATE**

JSfiddle showing the JS needed to assign the `quantity` parameter of the `a` element to the input's value: https://jsfiddle.net/bar7core/

Comment: where should i place this i need this value in place of 6 in the quantity variable as shown in link

Comment: When do you want the `href` to be updated? When the user types something in the quantity box?

Comment: Yes when the user types in quantity box it should get reflected

Answer (score 0):

So, this is only a demo as I can't have PHP code in fiddle and moreover I don't have those values. So, replace static values with your php variables.

```
var href = $("a.checkout").attr("href");

//Only if you want to keep the initial quanity when the text box is empty
var quantity =  $("#quantity").val();

$("#quantity").on("keyup", function() {
    var newQuantity = $.trim($(this).val());

    //Only if you want to keep the initial quanity when the text box is empty
    newQuantity = newQuantity == "" ? quantity : newQuantity;

    $("a.checkout").attr({
        "href": href.replace(/(&quantity=)([^&#]+)/i, '$1' + newQuantity)
    });
})
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity" id='quantity' value="10" size="40">
<a href="checkout.php?action=add&code=code&quantity=10" class="checkout">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
</a>
```

Here is a demo@[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/vfms4033/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the code but the thing here is that input textbox is coming in a loop so it will have multiple rows and a href values i want to apply it to particular row

Comment: Why do you make us all waste our time by providing no realistic information at all about the problem at hand? _The thing here is_ => Why wasn't this _thing_ in your question?

Comment: Sorry for not taking this thing in front of you earlier as i did not this would cause any problem

Comment: Is there any solution when it comes in a loop please help me i am struck in this for long time

Comment: Sure, edit your question and show me a sample of how it would look when the loop ran 3 times. Create a fiddle.